# Catch network errors using Awesomium

Tags: c#, error-handling, awesomium

I am creating a headless browser using Awesomium.  I want the browser to return Network Error codes, so  I know how/why it's breaking.

```
using (WebSession session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(new WebPreferences() { CustomCSS = "::-webkit-scrollbar { visibility: hidden; }" }))
        {
            using (WebView browserTab = WebCore.CreateWebView(1100, 600, session))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Starting WebCore v{WebCore.Version}");
                BadExample(browserTab, baseURL);
            }
        }

    static void BadExample(WebView browser, Uri url) {
browser.Source = (url + "/anyhing").ToUri();
        browser.LoadingFrameComplete += (sender, returnFrame) =>
        {
//NetError Code
        };
}
```

How do I use [enum NetError](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/T_Awesomium_Core_NetError.htm) to return the values I want?

Comment: Awesomium is pretty outdated. Better use a more modern alternative like for example [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/).

Answer (score 1):

You should subscribe to event `IWebView.LoadingFrameFailed` (browser in your case).

As long as there can be many frames on a page, the event will fire for every frame. Below is a snippet that I use in my project.

```
private void ViewOnLoadingFrameFailed(object sender, LoadingFrameFailedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsMainFrame)
    {
        var error = (NetError) e.ErrorCode;
        Logger.ErrorFormat("main frame loading failed: {0}-{1}", e.ErrorCode, e.ErrorDescription);
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.WarnFormat("frame #{0} loading failed: {1} - {2}", e.FrameId, e.ErrorCode, e.ErrorDescription);
    }
}
```